# Passing parameters to initialize function

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Looking at [realtime playground example](https://realtimeplayground.appspot.com).

For custom object, there [this call](https://github.com/googledrive/realtime-playground/blob/master/js/rtpg.custom.js#L91):

`custom.setInitializer(Movie, Movie.prototype.initialize);`

and `Movie.prototype.initialize` handler [takes two parameters](https://github.com/googledrive/realtime-playground/blob/master/js/rtpg.custom.js#L40)
 `name, director`

Where or how do these parameters get passed to initialize function?

Comment: Those arguments will probably be passed to the `Movie.prototype.initialize` function somewhere inside the `setInitializer` function.

Comment: actually this line is probably where it's happening: `var field = model.create(rtpg.custom.Movie, start.name, start.director);`

Comment: Yes, it looks like create function also defines arguments for initialize function.  https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.Model#gapi.drive.realtime.Model.prototype.create  `* var_args — Arguments to the newly-created object's initialize() method.`

Answer (score 1):

`create` function is the one that specifies arguments for `initialize` function.  See definition [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.Model#gapi.drive.realtime.Model.prototype.create)

`model.create` call passes `name, director` parameters here https://github.com/googledrive/realtime-playground/blob/master/js/rtpg.custom.js#L79

Thank you @basilikum for the tip.